# Django forms, specifying Model

Tags: python, django, forms

I have the following form:

```
class NotesForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
```

With the following views.py:

```
if request.POST:
        form = ThisForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            newentry = form.save()
            HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

And the folowing models.py

```
class TheModel(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
```

The thing is that it gives me `'ThisForm' object has no attribute 'save'` which it is most likely because I have not linked any model to it.

How can I link a model to the form in order to be able to `form.save()` to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you are wanting a `forms.ModelForm` instead of `forms.Form`:

```
class ThisForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TheModel
        fields = ['text']
```

Then your view should be able to `form.save()`. [See here for the official documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)